# CentOS 7 iptables marking SSH packets as invalid - GCloud

Tags: iptables, centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So I've decided to give GCloud a try for hosting some of my smalle projects. However when I'm configuring iptables on the server it marks the SSH packets as invalid. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong or if the issue is on Googles end.

[IPTables List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn8Sn.png)

[Log messages from IPTables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZVXe.png)

```
Jan 14 18:26:04 ************ kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=42:01:0a:a6:00:03:42:01:0a:a6:00:01:08:00 SRC=82.102.20.179 DST=10.166.0.3 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=6913 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=44759 DPT=22 WINDOW=1021 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0



327 39548 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
```

EDIT
I'm trying to add the following rule.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

Iptables -S output:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Why use iptables and not GCP's firewall? GCP's firewall is quite powerful. Also, can you please share an "iptables -S" or the rule you are trying to append?

Comment: Added the things you've asked for to the question. I've just always thought it was good practice to also setup firewall rules on the server itself even though GCP has a firewall in front of the server to.

Comment: `iptables -t mangle -S` would likely be a bit better match for the rule above. And output from `iptables-save` is even better as it includes all tables in its output.

Comment: Still not sure about what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain more the issue and maybe add the `iptables-save` output